# Array with range values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

```
a = [1, 2, 3..9, 10, 15, 20..43]
print a.include?(5) # Returns false
```

I was expecting it to return `true`, but `3..9` is not translated to `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

I am missing something silly but I can't figure it out. Basically I want to initialize it with both regular fixnums and ranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to splat it

```
a = [1, 2, *3..9, 10, 15, 20..43]
a.include?(5) # => true
```

Comment: Be careful splatting ranges though. It's very easy to create an array that won't fit into memory by splatting a range such as `*1..1_000_000_000_000`. The range is a very efficient way of expressing a big sequence, so if you're working with large ranges it'd be better to implement a smarter conditional test that knows how to compare against individual values, and for inclusion within ranges.

Comment: why not splat the second range as well? [1, 2, *3..9, 10, 15, *20..43]

Comment: @Nishu No reason. I just tried to show OP, what he missed, as he asked. If he need, he will splat it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a "lazier" approach that doesn't require you to convert ranges into array elements, try using the `===` (case equality) operator.

```
a = [1, 2, 3..9, 10, 15, 20..43]
a.any? { |x| x === 5 }
```

I recommend using this approach since it's far more efficient than splatting the range into separate elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without splat.

```
a = [1, 2, 3..9, 10, 15, 20..43]

a.any? {|i| i.kind_of?(Range) ? i.include?(5) : i == 5 }
# => true
```